# How can i mint solana tokens to increase the total supply? i burned lp

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter, mint, liquiditypool

I will give 1 sol to anyone who helps me with this. I didn't know how to do it. I issued a token, but even though I spent a lot of money, there was no entry. I burned the liquid, but the money inside is entirely my money. I will give 1 sol to anyone who tells me a way to get this again.

solscan: https://solscan.io/token/FZi4f1aaQSZTfgrZzaFApkQKFbRavcAUf74v38NJhVLt
contract adress: FZi4f1aaQSZTfgrZzaFApkQKFbRavcAUf74v38NJhVLt

Answer (score 1):

If u have burned the lp, there is no way to get it back, as burning an asset = destroying it for ever

I checked the CA on birdeye and it shows the token isn't mintable, so u cannot create more tokens.

Comment: Isn't there another way to do this?